# Объединение элементов list(списка) python

Tags: python, list

Есть список:

```
a = [[01.01.2020], ['Andre'], [23], [02.01.2020], ['John'], [24], [03.01.2020], ['Sasha'], [25]]
```

Нужно объединить в один список 3 элемента, в таком виде:

```
a = [[01.01.2020, 'Andre', 23], 
    [02.01.2020, 'John', 24], 
    [03.01.2020, 'Sasha', 25]]
```

Объединял в таком виде:

```
all=[]
for lst in a:
    for el in lst:
        all.append(el)
```

Но при этом все элементы добавляются в один список

Comment: `[a[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [['01.01.2020'], ['Andre'], [23], ['02.01.2020'], ['John'], [24], ['03.01.2020'], ['Sasha'], [25]]

# снимаем лишние скобки
b = [item[0] for item in a]

# собираем в тройки
c = list(zip(b[::3], b[1::3], b[2::3]))

# [('01.01.2020', 'Andre', 23), ('02.01.2020', 'John', 24), ('03.01.2020', 'Sasha', 25)]
print(c)
```